# Is there news about the podcast?

Tags: discussion, podcast

It's been two months, should we be expecting a new podcast? Is there somewhere on Stack Exchange to go for this information?

Comment: I think you have to say [Alex Miller](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159928/alex-miller)'s name three times fast.

Comment: @Tim don't forget it has to be in front of a mirror. At midnight.

Comment: @Pekka How about [two mirrors](http://xkcd.com/555/)?

Comment: Is there a tag we could add that would better catch the attention of those in the know?  Feature-request a new podcast?

Comment: I'm tempted to tag it [tag:support]. =P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, [the Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) (and the [podcasts category](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) in particular) is the only source of up-to-date information on the podcast. As you say, it's been over six to eight weeks since [the last podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/se-podcast-30-robert-cartaino-rebecca-chernoff/), whose blog entry enthusiastically states

> That’s it for Podcast #30, which is it for podcasts in 2011. See you next year!

So I guess the only thing we know for sure is: sometime this year (2012).

### Update (2012/02/06)

Now that [Jeff Atwood is leaving Stack Exchange](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html), it's somewhat unclear when the next podcast will be.

### Update (2012/03/02)

[Podcast #31](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-31-goodbye-jeff/) just went up yesterday.

Comment: I hope you're wrong there with that update.  Jeff seemed to say much less in the SE podcasts as compared to the old SO series: its been more about the guests.  So, he'll be missed, but the show must go on!

Comment: @martinclayton True enough. I'll edit my answer to remove the air of finality about it.

Comment: Having listened to every episode over the last year, following the often humorous, occasionally wise, and always inspiring journey from idea into a site for millions, I am truly sad to hear Jeff left.  But I guess all stories must end eventually...

Answer (score 2):

### [SE Podcast #33 – It’s Back!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/10/se-podcast-33-its-back/)

> It’s Back! Welcome to episode #33 of the Stack Exchange podcast.
> We’ve got a brand new co-host (Jay Hanlon, our new VP of Community
> Growth) plus our guest this week is David Fullerton, VP of Engineering
> at Stack Exchange.