# Mark Precognitive / Beta badges as closed

Tags: feature-request, badges, area-51

SO is an established site and nobody can earn these badges anymore. I understand why they are displayed in the list of badges. I myself visited AREA 51 to catch some aliens, oops see incubating sites.

What I propose is to mark these badges as Closed on SO. It will make it clear that it is not possible to earn them on SO anymore. There is already precedent:

```
Analytical - Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)
```

We can update badges description in similar way with *(closed)* suffix. It will not hurt anybody's feeling but it will help to clarify them.

This post is related to, but is not the same as, the following post:

[Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges)

I'm not suggesting these badges be removed from the list, merely that it be annotated in some way.

*Update*

Please change Beta badge description to "Actively participated in the private beta **for this site**".

Comment: I always wonder why people use upvotes/downvotes as kind of poll on Meta. Downvote description: "This question does not show any research effort, it is ucclear or not useful".

Comment: I don't think "closed" accurately conveys that message. I'm not really sure what message it conveys. I don't think it makes much sense in the context of earning badges. At most, I'd go with an asterisk that mentions that the badge can no longer be earned *on this site* (that emphasized part is very important).

Comment: I would call for any improvement. It took me some time until I get it. And then, the description was clear. If there is some indication, it would help. See how many duplicates the linked question have. So it is a problem.

Comment: @LeosLitrerak: that's why this question was posted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227015/can-we-change-the-mouse-over-text-for-voting-on-meta

Comment: I do not like association between negative votes and reputation. Why am I punished when my proposal is OK but somebody does not agree with it? It is better to leave disagree comment.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Because the voter feels *it's not a useful contribution*.  That's what the vote means.  If you read the answer to the linked post you'd see that using the term "agreement/disagreement" is highly misleading in this context.

Comment: But if it is just disagreement, why does it cost my reputation? It is discouraging to ask questions in meta, I do not feel friendly and constructive atmosphere here.

Answer (score 2):

> It will make it clear that it is not possible to earn them on SO anymore.

What is unclear about the current text?

> Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase
>
> Actively participated in the private beta

It tells you how to earn them.  They aren't closed at all - they represent exactly the conditions they intend to represent, and they continue to represent those conditions.

How would putting `(closed)` on them clarify them any further than they already are? Who, exactly, is confused?

If anything, adding such a suffix would only cause confusion.

Comment: Is "Actively participated in the private beta" clear? It could be understood that you can participate in any stackexchange beta.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Really? Then do you also wonder if the `guru` badge on this site might actually mean that you were a guru on another site? If so, then adding, "closed" won't help - you'll have to change the wording to include "stackoverflow" or similar.

Comment: This is a retrospectivity issue - when you know it, you cannot understand why somobody can have a problem with it. It is like cycling - once you get it, it is clear. So yes, I publicly disclose, I believed that participating in beta from Area 51 is a way to get this badge. Now I know that all SE sites are equal and independent. And not it seems evident. But should you ask newbie, you may get other responses. Ware other people shoes.

Comment: @LeosLiterak A badge's description doesn't aim to teach you badges are not global, but very specific for a SE site.

Comment: The "the Area 51 proposal for this site" part is very clear: If you are on Stack Overflow, _this site_ means Stack Overflow, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: @kiamlaluno "Actively participated in the private beta" - I started with this badge and later I read Precognitive description. So at least beta badge shall be modified to "Actively participated in the private beta for this site" to make it clear.

Comment: @LeosLiterak "Actively participated in ***the*** private beta". I find it hard to find any other meaning than the current site's private beta. Maybe, just maybe, adding that extra bit would be useful, but I honestly doubt it would clarify it for many people.

Comment: @3ventic try to search for this badges in meta, you will find many similar questions where askers did not understand their meaning as well. When you know it, it is hard to understand other people that do not know it yet

Comment: @3ventic ad "the site" - english is not my native language so I do not feel it is equivalent to "this".

Answer (score 0):

It's ok if there is some mystery to the site, some corners you don't understand right away, some jokes that seem to be shared by those who've been here longer than you. Not too much, not so much you feel excluded, but a little, so that you explore and find out and dig into the history and character of the place. It's a delicate balance, but I think these unearnable badges are part of the charm, and should stay just as they are.

Comment: I am analytic person, not romantic. I see a problem, not mystery. ;-)