# Should Badges that can no longer be awarded be removed from the 'Badges' panel?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

I was browsing the Stack Overflow badges tab earlier, and noticed there are some badges that can no longer be awarded.

For example;

- Analytic
- Precognitive
- Beta

These are badges that, unless I'm misunderstanding what they mean, are no longer possible to be awarded, which brings me to the question, should they still be visible on the 'Badges' tab?

I'm not saying remove them from users who have earned them, just hide them on the badges page, or perhaps even better, have a separate section at the bottom for 'Retired Badges', or something similar?

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227342/mark-precognitive-beta-badges-as-closed

Comment: @ShadowWizard Apologies, I did have a brief look, but never saw that one

Comment: All good, it's not trivial to find. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the reason for the existence of the [Badges page](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges) properly, it is not only to inform about the badges that can be awarded but also to describe the badges which are already awarded.

If we remove them, the users having the badges will leave the visitors wondering for the description of the badges they "earned" at some point of time.

We can, however, have a category for badges that can no longer be awarded, but the question is, upto what point it is necessary? The description of the badge(es) is clear enough for the reader to understand that this badge is not possible to be awarded anymore.

Comment: I just think something like that would be nice for users who are looking on the 'Unearned' section, if they had earned all of the badges possible that can still be earned, for them to see a clean page and see no old badges that appear 'Unearned'. If they were in their own category, this would at least provide a view of having earned all of the badges, if that makes sense?

Comment: @David I see it from this point of view that, any badge, that cannot be earned, is unearned. Just try to compare from the point of view of those who had earned it. Call that a _"timely bonus"_ :)