# How to improve feedback to other/new users?

Tags: feature-request

As a newbie I'm struggling with a lot of new things of Stack Overflow and other sites. How to get reputation is one topic, where I found [this interesting post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/351866) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/7564182). Apart from that, it is hard to answer a question on the edge of timing, because the more experienced ones are faster and better with answers.

In this chase I've realized that I'm wasting my time by clicking on questions which I've already read. Here is my idea:

**Provide a fixed feedback-menu** with

- I don't want to see it again because:

  1. I cannot answer it.
  2. The question is unclear.
  3. The question doesn't fit [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
- Perhaps there are more feasible feedback options, but what should be the **consequences**?

  1. I don't want to view this question again (if I cannot answer yet?).
  2. As long as it is not updated, I don't want to see it again (for 2.+3.).

And for users who want to see these ignored questions again, we can add a flag, `ignored:1`, to the search options.

Comment: Downvote/vote to close the post.  Then it's sending that signal not just to future you, but to everyone else, so that they can all get that same benefit.

Comment: I've read about downvoting, but then the affected user especially new users don't know, WHY. With feedback, perhaps that a comment is needed before downvoting that should help also newbies.

Comment: The user isn't going to know why people are ignoring their question either, if lots of people are just silently ignoring their question.  By all means, comment if you think you can help the author improve their question (and you think that they're likely to be able/willing to actually do so), but don't let that stop you from closing close-worthy questions or downvoting unhelpful questions.

Comment: the required comment with a down vote has been suggested before many times and none of those have made it passed meta.

Comment: My standard feedback should save time for everyone. By giving a standard response and also only see it, when necessary.

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233564/193412

Comment: On [Forth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth), there is plenty of time to answer (on the order of days).

Comment: For instance, right now, the latest question is 2 days old.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is unclear or otherwise not a good question, consider downvoting it or flagging it to be closed. You may prefer to edit it, or to leave comments for the poster encouraging them to edit it, so that it becomes a good question.

If the question is a fine question, but just of no interest to you, consider adding one of its tags to your ignored tags. Also consider adding things to your preferred tags. On sites other than SO this will cause questions to be greyed out (ignored) and highlighted yellow (preferred.) On SO it will have a more dramatic effect with ignored questions not even shown to you and more preferred than ordinary questions shown to you.

If the question is in a tag that interests you, but you just can't answer it and also don't care what the answer is, don't click on it. If you find yourself clicking on it and then being surprised by what you read: "oh it's this thing again, I didn't care about that yesterday," then consider editing the title to better represent the content.

When looking at the front page and considering clicking on a question, get in the habit of observing the activity listed (eg asked 38 min ago, or answered 1 hr ago, or modified 2 min ago) to help you decide whether you want to click or not.

Comment: Ok, I see the point(s).

Comment: Don't forget that voting requires reputation - for a completely new user, these are not actionable things.

Comment: Agreed, @Oded, but all are verbed "Consider" meaning if the person can't do it, they just don't do it. Only the first paragraph contains rep-limited actions, and contains a non-rep-limited one (suggesting an edit) as well.