# Reposting a closed or held question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In theory, when a question is voted closed, then the OP edits the question to be site-appropriate, the question will be added to a review queue.

However, in practice, the question, now made good, may possibly never make it back to the land of living questions, due to the original swarm of downvotes.

If a user cannot reclaim the now-good question into an upvote situation, what should they do to revive interest in the question?

Comment: Questions that are edited to the point that they're *actually good questions* are *very* likely to get reopened when fixed.  It's the ones that make edits without actually fixing the problems with the question that tend to stay closed.

Comment: Is this a bad question because the answer is "no", or is this a bad question because it's inappropriate material for meta.stackexchange?  This is my first post on here, so I'm apparently confused as to the purpose of the site...

Comment: In fact, my question is very similar to the prototypical question provided as an example in the official meta.stackexchange tour.  Comments to help me improve my question would be appreciated.

Comment: the downvotes are because you are making a false assertion (that once close, questions that deserve opening aren't re-opened - something you could not know because once re-opened you can't tell it was ever closed) and you are suggesting subverting the rules and doing something that shouldn't be done as a way to get what you want.

Comment: "Should a user just delete and repost the question at that point?" does NOT suggest that a user should do that thing, it ASKS IF a user should do that thing.

Comment: Also, it has been my experience that questions do not get reopened, or viewed, or upvoted once they have been closed, even when I make them of a quality of other questions of mine that have been well received. So I can know that, and I stand by that assertion.

Comment: @Scott give an example, by the timeline we should be able to tell if the review ended up with "Leave closed" or if it has not been reviewed

Comment: @Tensibai I have a tendency to delete my severely downvoted questions, to prevent further downvoting.  Wish I could do the same for this question, or that somebody would provide me with advice to improve it :)

Comment: Okay. I will try to phrase questions to "suggest" the answer that people want to hear in the future.  :)

Comment: *swarm of down votes* and *down vote hell* are phrases that seem to suggest you feel down votes are a bad thing. Most of the meta regulars think down votes are an awesome way to moderate a post. That might influence their voting on your question as well.

Comment: I do not feel that down votes are necessarily a bad thing, but a previously bad question that is now a good question will retain the down votes from the previous badness.  This has a tendency to direct attention away from the question.

Comment: *"because once re-opened you can't tell it was ever closed) ..."* - this is not true. The edit history contains a record of when and by whom a question is closed or reopened, and the majority reason for a closure.

Comment: "Should a user just delete and repost the question at that point?“ - Absolutely not.  “I have a tendency to delete my severely downvoted questions, to prevent further downvoting.” - If you continue to do this then eventually you will be unable to ask new questions.  Questions ban exists to stop this behavior.

Comment: @Meta'sMug, "downvotes don't mean it's a bad question...": This doesn't seem to be the official meta.stackexchange stance anymore.  The help tour specifically designates "On posts tagged feature-request, voting can indicate agreement or disagreement". However, it looks as though this may be a new development, as suggested by this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187018/voting-on-meta-is-not-just-for-disagreement-update-the-help-center-to-reflect

Comment: @Servy, at the time, I thought that maybe I was inclined to defer to your knowledge, having myself limited knowledge of the site.  However, I have continued to experience a situation where closed questions are very difficult to get reopened, no matter what amount of effort has been put into cleaning up the situation.  As such, your statement that "questions ... are very likely to get reopened when fixed" requires evidence.

Comment: @Scott And what are those questions that have been fixed *and actually corrected the problems that caused them to be close*, have not been reopened?

Comment: @Servy, I unfortunately have not been compiling a list of examples for this purpose, but most recently I have been confounded by [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018108/python-round-scalar-up-to-nearest-non-integer-value#comment102727592_56018108) closure.  The OP had already pointed out why it wasn't a dupe.  I tried to perform some edits to make the OP's reasoning absolutely clear, but I'm pretty sure that there is just no rescuing the question.  Not because it's not a valid question, but because un-duping it is a monumental task.

Comment: Also, @Servy, I'm not entirely certain that the burden of proof is upon me here.  If you seem to think that when problems with questions get fixed, they get reopened, why should you not have to provide evidence that that is the case?

Comment: @Scott *You* are the one asserting that the systems already in place to reopen closed questions aren't working, and thus the burden of proof is on you to show that that's the case.  As for the question you linked, I fail to see how the information in the duplicate doesn't address the problem at hand, as the other question appears to address precisely the concerns that that question raises in the same situation (although it's outside of my expertise).  It would seem you also failed to convince those who are experts in that subject as well.

Comment: @Servy "It would seem you also failed to convince those who are experts in that subject" Yet another claim that requires proof.  My edit puts the question to the top of the feed.  Who are the experts that you claim is reviewing the re-open request?  They don't exist.

Comment: @Servy, if the question was "on hold", [then it would end up in a re-open review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/341762), but there is no guarantee that anyone reviewing it is any more of an expert on the subject than you are.

Comment: @Scott You think literally no one is looking at Python questions on this site?  That's a rather extreme position to take, without any supporting evidence.

Comment: @Scott And the fact that, even now, you *still* can't explain why the question isn't answered by the duplicate, doesn't support your position that the question should be reopened.  That you can only say that no one looks at Python questions on this site instead isn't a compelling argument.

Comment: I think that, as I have said, that for two identical questions at the top of the feed, except that one is closed and one is not, the likelihood that the un-closed one gets an upvote, and the closed one gets crickets is very high.  The question got an extra 10 views or so after my edit.  Probably a few of those are experts.  Probably they looked at the question and said "oh, its a dupe... NEXT!"

Comment: @Servy I have explained in the question comments.  So has the OP.   This is not the place to explain it, and your request that I explain it here makes clear that you have no interest in constructive conversation.  I will now cease communications with you.

Comment: @Scott Ah, so the question *doesn't* explain the difference, only the comments do, and your statement that you edited the question to clarify the different wasn't true (I of course looked at your edit, as you mentioned it, but it does not clarify the point), as you only noted the differences in the comments.  That is of course your problem.  You should be editing *the question*, to make the differences clear, not posting comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with considering it "ok" to re-post instead of going through the reopen process, is that most people that ask off-topic questions do so because they don't understand the posting rules, or the *scope*, of the site they're asking on.

The Stack Exchange system (not its moderators, not its users: *the system itself*) will automatically block a user from asking new questions, if they can't be bothered to learn the rules and play by them. The details are unknown, but shortly put, if you have closed, downvoted questions, deleting them won't fix your "standing" in the system - deleted posts *still* count towards an automatic ban.

The idea is that users are encouraged to **edit their bad posts into shape**, rather than deleting and re-posting. You see some people don't care about the rules, and will re-post a crap question all day if they think that's how they're going to get an answer. The system protects itself specifically against that, and vigorously.

If your question was put on hold, it's very likely that at least one user commented on it (often with a canned comment, if the question displays a common misunderstanding of how Stack Exchange Q&A sites work). When you edit your post, @ping that user to let them know you've read the link(s) they provided to `/help/how-to-ask` or `/help/on-topic`, and have edited your post accordingly.

If you *did* get your question back on track with that edit, a close vote can be retracted, a downvote can be reversed, and an obsolete comment thread can be wiped out by a moderator.

If an edit is suggested to your question while it's on hold, and that edit does not make your question on-topic, **reject that edit**: only the first edit made to a question after it's put "on hold" will make the post enter the "reopen" review queue - if the edit isn't making the post on-topic, the reviewers will vote to keep it closed instead of reopening it, and when you *do* edit it into shape, your question will not make it to the reopen queue, and then yes, it can become pretty hard to get your question reopened.

---

#### TL:DR;

Don't delete your downvoted posts, edit them into shape instead. Otherwise you risk falling under some threshold and blocking yourself from asking further questions. Not even moderators can lift an automatic question ban: you're in charge of your own standing.

As for the "initial swarm of downvotes" - deleting the post only makes it worse. If you have enough reputation score, you can put up a bounty to draw attention: if it really *is* a good question now, that doesn't deserve such a negative score, the bounty period should help turning it around.

In any case, the single best thing to do is: don't do it again. Read and understand the `/help/how-to-ask` and `/help/on-topic` links on the site(s) you're asking on, read some upvoted questions on that site, see what they all have in common, and make that an ingredient in your own future posts.

Comment: "It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site." -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: "Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified." -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: This provides an incentive to delete one's downvoted posts, and to repost the edited made-better-version. I'm not saying it's good or bad, just pointing it out.

Comment: @Scott the internals of how automatic question-ban works aren't disclosed, but as a moderator on a SE site I can assure you that deleting your downvoted posts is *not* helping your standing, *does* count toward a Q-ban, and if you un-delete a deleted post that's sitting at -10, the votes and corresponding reputation adjustments will be re-applied. [I've commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that#comment984458_5222) on that meta post to get it clarified: nullified doesn't mean what you think it does here

Comment: @Scott re the first quote, 3 paragraphs above that quote clearly says "If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that **will continue to count against your account even if the post is deleted**! Whenever possible, try to **fix posts instead of deleting them**"

Comment: Yes, but that is relating to Q-banning, not to rep. There is a rep incentive to delete your own downvoted questions. I'm not arguing that one should or should not delete one's downvoted questions, I just thought that it was interesting that there is an incentive to do so, since users may not know about Q-banning, but will know about rep. My immediate instincts upon seeing my rep go down due to downvotes is to attempt stem the tide. Now, having learned more about the subject, I will think twice, but less informed users may not.

Comment: @Scott Any user who would be effected by a question ban is warned well before it happens.  If they choose to ignore the warnings from the system and other users then that’s on them.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not appropriate to just re-ask your question when it's closed.  The reopen process is there for a reason (to ensure that questions really have been fixed before answers are posted to them) and trying to subvert that process by posting duplicate questions is not appropriate.